# × Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): this.handleUpdate is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

I'm a new in React! I'm making e-commerce store for project. It is first time to write async and await. through fetch, I should receive backpack data! but I can't pass the data in context.js to backpackList.js because of this error!
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): this.handleUpdate is not a function <
const data = await getResponse.json(); but when i display console. this data can be seen in console.
this.handleUpdate(data); but this function do not work. how can i fix this problem.
Thank you so much!!

```
context.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const ProductContext = React.createContext();
const ProductConsumer = ProductContext.Consumer;

class ProductProvider extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      totalProducts: 0, 
      isLogin: false,
      bagInfoForNoneUser: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/data/totalProducts.json', {
      method: 'GET',
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          totalProducts: data[0].totalProducts,
        });
      });
  }    
  handleUpdate = data => {
    this.setState({
      bagInfoForNoneUser: [this.state.bagInfoForNoneUser, data],
    });
  };

  async noneUserCart() {
    const url = '/data/getdata.json';
    const getResponse = await fetch(url);
    const data = await getResponse.json();
    this.handleUpdate(data); //this part error, 
  }
  
  handleTotalProduct = total => {
    this.setState({ totalProducts: total });
  };

  getToken = () => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    return token;
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <ProductContext.Provider
        value={{
          ...this.state,
          handleCart: this.handleCart,
          getToken: this.getToken,
          noneUserCart: this.noneUserCart,
        }}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </ProductContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

export { ProductProvider, ProductConsumer };
```

```
BackPackList.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ProductConsumer } from '../../context';

export default class BackpackList extends Component {
  render() {
    const {
      backpackdata,
      backdescdata,
      isdescOpen,
      showDesc,
      descClose,
      rangenumone,
      rangenumtwo,
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <div> 
        {backdescdata.map((bag, inx) => {
          return (
            <>
              {isdescOpen && bag.id > rangenumone && bag.id < rangenumtwo && (
                <div className="listDescContainer" key={inx}>
                  <div className="listDescBox">
                    <img
                      alt="bag"
                      className="descImg"
                      src={bag.image_url}
                    ></img>
                    <div className="descText">
                      <div className="descName">{bag.model_number}</div>
                      <div className="descPrice">
                        A Blast from the Past, {bag.price}
                      </div>
                      <ProductConsumer> // !!!this part! when i onclick, go to the context.js !
                        {value => (
                          <div
                            className="cartBtn"
                            onClick={() => {
                                const result = value.noneUserCart(bag.id);
                                console.log(result);
                            }}
                          >
                           add to cart
                          </div>
                        )}
                      </ProductConsumer>

                      <span className="descClosebtn" onClick={descClose}>
                        X
                      </span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              )}
            </>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KavNT.png)

Comment: Can you post the full error stack trace?

Comment: Try changing it to an async function,  handleUpdate = async (data) => {....}

Comment: oh! sorry! I update a picture!

Comment: I fixed this error! I don’t know what to say! Thank yo so much! htk!

Comment: @MIAㅜ_ㅜ Glad that it helped you. Its ntk btw :)